# Converting/Modifying non-standard string into datetime for Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

So I have a set of data for sales by month (not in order) but the string format for the `data` column comes out as `month/day/year hour:minute`

For example: `04/19/19 18:27` and it is a string object.

How am I able to convert this into datetime where I only take the month and day?

Also, how can I simply take only the month and convert it to an integer?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` should work out of the box; the format is pretty standard and the month comes first, which is also pd.to_datetime's default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert it to a datetime, use `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

To get the month out of it, use this after you've run the above:

```
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
```

To convert it into a `YYYY-MM` format:

```
df['year-month'] = df['a'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

As we discussed [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240367/discussion-between-swordlordswamplord-and-richardec), this wasn't working because the column names were copied as rows into the dataframe at various points.

Comment: is there any way I can convert the initial dates into just the month/day?

Comment: Check the answer now, @swordlordswamplord. ;)

Comment: okay for some reason I get a value error: ValueError: time data '04/19/19 08:46' does not match format '%m%d%Y %H:%M' (match). I used both capital and lowercase Y

Comment: You have to use lowercase `y`, because that's for the double-digit years. `Y` is for 4-digit years. It looks like you don't have the slashes in the dateformat though. `%m%d%Y` should be `%m/%d/%Y`

Comment: ValueError: time data 'Order Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' (match) I can link the csv file if you want

Comment: Okay, please do, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240367/discussion-between-swordlordswamplord-and-richardec).